# Single filter with ManyToMany queryset on Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to perform some filter based on manytomany fields from different models, but am stuck.

I have these models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    eventtype = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=event_type)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    values = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True, blank=True)

class Userlogin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Events(models.Model):
    eventtype = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status, verbose_name='Status', default='I')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

So based on the categories my user choose (Userlogin class), I want to filter the events.
Example:

```
Userlogin 80 has choose ['openair','night']

Events:

Event 1 - ['openair','couples']

Event 2 - ['couples']

Event 3 - ['night','openair']
```

That should return Events 1 and 3.

So I have a queryset that has some other evaluations, and now I want to "join" the user categories with the Events categories.

```
events = Events.object.filter(status='A')
events = events.filter(eventtype='X)
#some other complex filtering, based on other models
events = events.filter(category??????) #stuck here
```

How could I do that? The trick here is that I need to keep using this queryset, so I would like to go with the filter method.

I am using django 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# returns all the events which have any of the user_login categories
events = events.filter(category__in=user_login.category.all()).distinct()
```

The django documentation provides details on querying m2m relationship across models. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/